# Why am i redirected to login page on the service provider following an idp initated login

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, single-sign-on, saml-2.0

**A bit of context**

I have an asp.net mvc app that is going to be used by a company that is using saml sso to log in to their apps. They have an identity provider and they asked me to configure sso on my application. From what i understood the connections that are going to be made are going to be only idp initiated.

**What i tried**

I have used the sustainsys saml package and followed their configuration guide. The only changes i have made are in the web.config file, since that is what was required in the guide.

**The problem**

When someone is trying to log in at the idp, the login is successful on the idp part, but when redirecting to my application, no user is logged in and the the login page is displayed.

I did not find any specific information on this kind of problem. I also don't know if any code changes are necessary or if what i did in web.config is enough.

Has anyone encountered this issue and found a way to solve it?

Does anyone have a more technical specific guide for configuring sso on a service provider?

Comment: We have no idea if your code changes and config are correct either, because you haven't shown them to us, or described the operating environment in sufficient detail

Comment: If 'persistent NameId format' is being used, then it's actually a trigger for the SP to perform 'account linking' instead of 'SSO'. To perform 'account linking', the SP needs to know the identity of the user and hence needs to show an authentication dialogue.  You may check if this is the case.

Comment: Have you enabled "allowUnsolicitedAuthnResponse"?